# How to extract JSON from a List in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to display a ListView.builder from a list where data came from Firestore. I get and store my datas like this

```
List filterMangaList = [];
Future<List> getFavMangas() async {
    var value = await firestore.collection("users").doc(user.uid).get();
    final favMangasList = value.data()?["fav_manga"];
    filterMangaList.clear();
    for (var i in favMangasList) {
      final mangas = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('mangas')
          .where('title', isEqualTo: i)
          .get();
      final filterManga = mangas.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();
      filterMangaList.add(filterManga);
    }
    return filterMangaList;
  }
```

The list I want to extract data is `filterMangaList` who looks like this

`[[{total_chapter: 361, pic: https://images.pexels.com/photos/213780/pexels-photo-213780.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500, title: My Hero Academia}], [{total_chapter: 700, pic: https://images.pexels.com/photos/213780/pexels-photo-213780.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500, title: Naruto}]]`

And my ListView.builder looks like this

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: getFavMangas(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot future) {
    if (!future.hasData)
      return Container();
    else {
      var filterMangaList = future.data;
      print(filterMangaList);
      return ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: filterMangaList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            child: Text(filterMangaList[index]["title"]),
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }),
```

but I have this error:

> _TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index')

I think it is because I have one too much `[]` but I don't know how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually have one `[]` too few in your code.

This is your data structure

```
[
  [{
    total_chapter: 361,
    pic: "https: //images.pexels.com/photos/213780/pexels-photo-213780.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
    title: My Hero Academia
  }],
  [{
    total_chapter: 700,
    pic: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/213780/pexels-photo-213780.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
    title: Naruto
  }]
]
```

So it's an array of arrays with properties. That's because you have a list of results for each query.

To get the data from the above structure, you can do:

```
child: Text(filterMangaList[index][0]["title"]),
```

But that will only show the first result of each query, which is probably not what you want.

---

To see all the results of all the queries, you have to add them to a flat list instead of a nested list. A simple way to do that is:

```
filterMangaList.addAll(filterManga);
```

With that change your `filterMangaList` contains a flat list of all results from all queries, that you can then display in the `ListView` with your orignal code.